# Implementing different stages in Veins Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to implement GPGR protocol in Omnet++ using veins framework. But the problem is I am unable to understand the 2 stages of veins and what are they used for? Can anyone guide me please

Comment: What stages are you referring to exactly?
The [Multi-Stage Initialization](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec149)?

Comment: @floxyz we found a sample code stating

 BaseApplLayer::initialize(stage);
if(stage==0){ //some code }

so i wanted to ask what these stages were?

Comment: Please read the link from my previous comment....

Answer (score 2):

As @floxyz said the best info can be found in OMNeT++ manual, but basically stages in the initialization process are used as "waves" of creating the modules and setting up the parameters that will be used during simulation.

It is especially useful if there are dependencies between the modules. What happens is that you would first want to create the "parent" module and then the ones which depend on it.